# Java Clear Map of Map

Tags: java

What is the most appropriate way to `clear` a `Map` of a `Map`, assuming I simply want to clear all entries in the top-level `Map`?

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> nestedMap;
```

---

**Method A: Clear the top-level map only.**

```
nestedMap.clear();
```

---

**Method B: Clear the inner maps, then clear the top-level map.**

```
for (Map<Integer, Integer> innerMap: nestedMap.values()) {
    innerMap.clear();
}
nestedMap.clear();
```

Comment: Do you just need the outer map cleared, or do you also need to ensure the inner maps are cleared as well? Do which ever one does what you need done.

Comment: I got my answer, but I edited my question a little bit. I was concerned about garbage collection, but it appears java is smart enough to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing just the outer map would be fine, unless you wanted to retain the empty inner maps for later use. By clearing the external map, the internal maps should be garbage collected.